# changing name of project in Facebook and Google sign in methods

Tags: ios, facebook-login, google-signin

i have recently integrated  Facebook and google sign in methods into my app however the app does not particularly show the desired "name" upon signing in using the methods

I have tried changing the Display name on my app but it is still not showing it.

I would want the "name" on the Alert view to be different / customised Here is the screenshot of what i mean.

[image]

In this case, i would like the "ChatSDKSwift" to be a custom name that i would like, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Are you creating this alert yourself?

Comment: No this is not created by me @manish_kumar

Comment: Are you using any third party(like SDTwitter) for Google/Facebook sign in, as many a times I have done this, but I never saw this alert?

Answer (score 4):

You can change it form **Build Setting** -> **product name** change it to your app display name.

By default it take **target name**.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can change it by editing the `CFBundleName` property in your `Info.plist` file. In Xcode, it is listed as "Bundle name".